# Order groups by partition size in sql?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to select the group_items of the top N largest groups with the same grouping_attribute from a table, and doing something like this:

```
SELECT grouping_attribute, group_item, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grouping_attribute ORDER BY ???) AS rn
FROM a_table
WHERE rn < N;
```

But I don't know what to put in the ORDER BY clause to make it happen. I'm trying to order the rows by the size of their corresponding partitions. COUNT(*) doesn't run. I was hoping there was some way to refer to the size of the partition, but I can't find anything.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: I'm trying to add an edit, but it doesn't seem to want to go through. In the meantime, a better explanation of my end goal is that I'm trying to group rows by a certain variable, and then return the rows from the largest groups.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want `count(*)` not `row_number()`.  Use `count(*)` to get the size of the partitions and then order the resulting rows afterwards.  For instance:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT grouping_attribute, group_item, 
             COUNT(*) over (partition by grouping_attribute) as cnt
      FROM a_table
     ) a
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

Comment: I don't think you need the subquery here, you should be able to order by `cnt` without it

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to do it without a subquery, because once I do the ordering I then wanted to have a "where rownum<N" instead of having to select everything first. The row_number is because I need to take the top N rows, not just order them.

Comment: @RachaelMiller . . . You can add `row_number()` into the query as well.  It doesn't seem needed for the `order by`.